# How to find out definition via hovering a document selector? help me :)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

I want to use the VSCode API to find the importing path of a variable when the cursor hovers on a document selector. Currently, I must click a document selector to go to its definition. I suspect I can call the VSCode API to fetch the information of a variable hovered on, so that I can get the importing path of a variable.